# Cookie Consent Needed for Higher Education Website

Tags: web-development, cookie

I work for a private college in California. Our site is mainly for prospective students. We use Google Analytics, but anonymize user IP addresses.

What are the rules/laws for needing a cookie consent screen for higher education websites? Specifically for private colleges and universities?

Comment: The laws about cookies vary by jurisdiction.    Where is your private college or university located?

Comment: What does this website do?   The laws about cookies require different things based on what information is being collected and what is stored in cookies.

Comment: We are located in California and our website is mainly for prospective students.

Comment: California is a bad place to have a website these days because of the CCPA.  You have to worry about far more than cookies.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller We are a non-profit, so CCPA doesn't apply to us.